# How do I configure Hibernate to fail startup if database is down?

Tags: hibernate

I'm using hibernate+spring (but I had the same problem with hibernate alone). When the app starts up, hibernate says it is building a session factory. The fact is that even if the db is down (in my case mysql), hibernate doesn't fail, it just starts up without even an exception. I'd like it to fail, is there a way to do that in the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a connection pool (c3p0 for example), it verifies the connection and fails on startup. [Look here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToconfiguretheC3P0connectionpool) for a how-to

You can also use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate` - its main purpose is to validate whether the structure of the schema matches the entities, but it means that hibernate will attempt a connection, and throw an exception if it fails.

Comment: I'm using org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource, for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto, currently it is set to update, later I'd like to write some routine that do a create only by code. It's a development arrangement. Do you have any clues about data source?

Comment: @gotch4 my current setup is using hbm2ddl and c3p0 and it fails to start if the database is down.